# Is this the proper Syntax for Caml Querys?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have a working Caml Query like so:

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ptli_TravelersEmail\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + payeename + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

...that retrieves "records" from a Sharepoint list where the value in the 'ptli_TravelersEmail' field equates to the value of the passed-in arg "payeename".

To add another clause to the query, to retrieve "records" where the former holds true but also where the value in the 'ptli_preparer' field equates to the value of the passed-in arg "username," do I need to repeat an entire "Where.Eq.FieldRef Name.Value..Value.Eq.Where" section, like this:

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ptli_TravelersEmail\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + payeename + '</Value></Eq></Where><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\'ptli_preparer\' /><Value Type=\'Text\'>' + username + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>
```

...or is my syntax off?

I could just try it and find out, I know, but the build/run/test process in Sharepoint takes quite awhile, and I'm hoping some Caml expert knows right off the bat.

Comment: Its not very clear if you want to obtain records from any of the conditions or if both conditions must match in order to obtain records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the general format for a [CAML query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467521(v=office.14).aspx):

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_of_field" />
                <Value Type="Text">The value to filter against</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

`<Eq>` means "Equals." You can also use comparisons like `<Neq>` (Not Equals), `<Lt>` (Less than), `<Leq>` (Less than or equal to), `<Gt>` (Greater than), `<Geq>` (Greater than or equal to), `<Contains>`, `<IsNull>`, and `<IsNotNull>`.

When you want your CAML query to have multiple conditions, you can combine two of them inside a set of `<And>` tags ([documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms196939(v=office.14).aspx)).

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_of_field1" />
            <Value Type="Text">The value to filter against</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_of_field2" />
            <Value Type="Text">The value to filter against</Value>
        </Eq>
    </And>
</Where>
```

You can nest `<And>` tags inside other `<And>` and `<Or>` tags to build arbitrarily complicated queries.

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_of_field1" />
            <Value Type="Text">The value to filter against</Value>
        </Eq>
        <And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_of_field2" />
                <Value Type="Text">The value to filter against</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_of_field3" />
                <Value Type="Text">The value to filter against</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```

The exact syntax used in the `<Value>` element can vary depending on the type of field being compared against. `Type="Text"` works for single line text fields, but lookup fields, date fields, and person or group fields have different syntax.

For more advanced CAML queries, note the placement of `OrderBy` and `RowLimit` elements:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_of_field" />
                <Value Type="Text">The value to filter against</Value>
            </Eq>
        </Where>
        <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name="Internal_Name_of_field" />
        </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <RowLimit>500</RowLimit>
</View>
```

Comment: You must be the Sharepoint grand poo-bah, head honcho, top cat, etc.